# How to iterate through multiple dropdown lists and access their option values

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, html-table

I'm writing the code for a basic GPA calculator. Basically, it's a 3-column-table, two text areas for the course name/credit hours and a dropdown list that contains letter grades (A+, C, B-) and their corresponding point values as the *option value*, like this

```
<td><select name="letterGrades">
<option value="0.7">A+</option>>
<option value="1.3">A-</option>>
<option value="2.7">C+</option>
</option>
</select>
</td>
```

I need to iterate through the rows, get the option value or "grade" for each course.

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {

 grade = table.rows[i].cells[2].options[letterGrades.selectedIndex].id; //is this allowed?
 credits = parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[1].value);
 totalHours += parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[1].value);  
 perCourse += grade*credits

 } 

totalGPA = perCourse/totalHours;
```

I realize there are other ways to assign the letters to their point values (arrays?) but I still don't know how to iterate through the dropdown lists and get their option values.

Comment: smells ironically like homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get to the `<select>` items first. If that's possible, I suggest you use `document.getElementsByTagName('select')` to get the list of all `<select>` tags on your page. Then, with each `<select>` tag, call `theSelectTag.getElementsByTagName('option')` (where `theSelectTag` is an object from the returned node list). You can then access their value through the `value` property (ya rly), and their label through the `textContent` property.

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` object, but you can pretty much treat it the same as an `Array`.

Comment: It worked, I had to use it to get the credit hours (textarea) too. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got everything to work thanks to zneak's answer. Here's how.

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {  //i=1, starts at the second row, assuming you have a header
    var grades = select[i].options[select[i].options.selectedIndex].value; //gets the selected item for each select tag from the dropdownlist
    credits = parseFloat(textarea[i].value); //same goes for textareas
    totalHours += parseFloat(textarea[i].value);            
    perCourse += grades*credits;    
}       
totalGPA = perCourse/totalHours;
```